# If equations derivated from KKT condition are too difficult to solve, what can we do in general?

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-optimization, quadratic-programming, karush-kuhn-tucker

I have the following optimization problem in $q \in \Bbb R^d$

$$\min_{q \geq 0} \quad q^T M q - w^T q $$

where matrix $M \in \Bbb R^{d \times d}$ is symmetric and positive semidefinite (PSD), $M_{ij} \ge 0$, $w \in \Bbb R^d$.

Since this is a convex function, using Lagrange multipliers and KKT, I get

$$
2Mq-w-\beta=0\\
q_i\ge0\\
\beta_i\ge0\\
q_i\beta_i=0\\
$$

Now I don't know how to continue. Could anyone give me some advice? Generally, what methods can be applied when equations derived from KKT condition are too difficult to solve?

Comment: look at how interior point methods solve the KKT conditions by iterative linearization

Comment: Most problems do not have an explicit formula for the optimal solution. Rather, they require some iterative scheme to find the solution. Luckily, convex programs can be solved easily and efficiently, and algorithms designed for them converge to KKT points. The main two classes of algorithms for such problems are first order methods and IPMs (interior point methods, which are second order).

Comment: @LinAlg Thank you, IPM is great!